# ¿Cómo referenciar esquema .XSD en archivo .XML en VisualStudio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

En mi aplicación tengo un archivo .xml y nesecito asociarle a este el esquema .xsd

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es bastante sencillo. Lo primero que debes hacer es abrir el archivo `xml` desde el Visual Studio. Una vez hecho esto, abre (si no la tienes ya abierta) la ventana de Propiedades:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Selecciona **Esquemas** y pulsa en el boton con los 3 puntos suspensivos que hay. Eso mostrará una pantalla como la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pulsa en **Agregar** y selecciona tu archivo `.xsd`

Por último, pulsa en la fila del archivo que acabas de añadir en la columna **Usar** y selecciona **Utilizar este esquema**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]